# Xcode v3 - Xcode v4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode3.2

How easily does Xcode 4 open up and control Xcode 3 projects?

Has anyone had compatability trouble with this yet, I don't want to install a new version to then find compatability faults with my projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had no problems opening Xcode 3 projects in Xcode 4 (and I no longer have Xcode 3 installed).  The actual project control files in Xcode 4 are 3.2 formatted, and Xcode 4 adds new files for its information.  I used to go back to Xcode 3 for deployments until the GM was released without issues.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have tried, there are no compatibility issues.. there is a chance that you might find a lot of memory issues/ warnings when u run/ analyze your code in xcode 4.. I dont know why that happens though... but other than that, your projects would run just fine with xcode 4.. and also, it is said that you can have both xcode 4 and xcode 3 installed at the same time without any problems...

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, I'm going to wait a while, perhaps for V4.1 when any bugs are taken out. I cant install both as they are such huge files. (still using a 2006 black macbook)

Comment: ok... that sounds like a good idea... i kinda feel xcode 4 is slowing my system a bit.. i am not sure whether it is due to someother reason but after I installed xcode 4 my system has slowed down a bit...